# Making part of span text as bold is not working

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a span in which I show some text, I want to make that bold. So I tried it like below

```
$('#spnApprRejInfo').text(response.d + " for " + "<b>" + spspnaname + "</b>");
```

and the span is below

```
<span id="spnApprRejInfo"></span>
```

but it is not making it bold. How should I do it ??

Comment: .html() not .text()

Comment: @TemaniAfif: thanks it worked. sorry for carelessness